# How to highlight an item in selectable without clicking on it (By code)?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

How to select(highlight) an item in selectable without clicking on it (By code)?

Such that I give it the index of which box to select/higlight

I create them dynamically like that

```
<div class="demo">  <ol id="selectable">  </ol></div>
```

and

```
var div = document.getElementById("selectable");
for(i=0; i<list.size; i++)
{    
    // It should look like that
    //<li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>    
    var properties = list[i].getProperties();    
    var aTag = document.createElement("li"); 
    //file name or something as ID    
    aTag.setAttribute('class',"ui-widget-content");    
    aTag.setAttribute('id',i);
    aTag.innerHTML = properties.fileName;
    //file name
    div.appendChild(aTag);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by selectable. Do you mean select box.

Comment: It's called "selectable" on jQuery-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select an index by using [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/). 0 being the first item.

```
$('item').eq(0).css('background-color','yellow'); //give the first item a yellow background.
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/FKvhG/

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit confused about which ID I should use in the $('') part. I have updated my question with a sample code. Could you please check it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`$('youritem').trigger('click');` will do the job! Easy solution.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit confused about which ID I should use in the $('') part. I have updated my question with a sample code. Could you please check it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `focus()`: `$('#element').focus();`

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit confused about which ID I should use in the $('') part. I have updated my question with a sample code. Could you please check it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("#id").val("example value")
```

to select an item given its value. You can find the value by index using

```
$("#id").find("option").eq(index).val()
```

so putting them together we have

```
$("#id").val($("#id").find("option").eq(index).val());
```

which does what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit confused about which ID I should use in the $('') part. I have updated my question with a sample code. Could you please check it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're select list has the id 'dropdown' and you want to select the first element, then this will work.

The eq() function will select whatever element you want, its zero based.

```
$('#dropdown').eq(0).attr("selected", true);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit confused about which ID I should use in the $('') part. I have updated my question with a sample code. Could you please check it? Thank you.